# Checkbox for array Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have an Activity and Type Model.

`Activities has_many Types`, `Types has_many Activities`

I would like to have checkboxes for all types when I create an activity so the ones that are checked, are the types of the new activity.

in my controller I did send all the types(@types) and in my view i did this

```
<div class = "field">
   Choose types:
   <% for type in @types %>
      <%= f.check_box :type %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

1. I get an error `undefined method 'type'`
2. I don't know what to do in the create action to get this to work

Comment: type is a reserve keyword for single table inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<%= check_box_tag 'type_ids[]', type.id %><%= type.name %>
```

Comment: I tried this and saw the html generated and it works. My problem is, how do I access this information in the controller?

Comment: params[:type_ids]=["and all checked type ids will come here"] #["1", "2"]

Answer (score 1):

```
   <% @types.each do |type| %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'type_ids[]', type.id %> <%= type.id %>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but now in my controller should i expect a `params[:type]`?

Comment: What is in `@types`? View generated html source.

Comment: @types =Types.all. So I want to be able to choose the type of the activity using this checkbox. I saw the html source and notices all the checkbox had the same value but I want the value for the checkbox to be the `id` of `type`